# Как на С++ разложить функцию sin(x)+cos(x) в ряд Тейлора через перегрузку операции помещения в поток вводы и извлечения из потока вывода?

Tags: c++, математика, перегрузка-операторов, поток-ввода, ряды

Столкнулся со следующей задачей:
Реализуйте модуль, подключение которого перегружает операции помещения в
поток вывода и извлечение из потока ввода для класса, содержащего методы разложения функции sin(x)+cos(x) в ряд Тейлора. На экран должно выводиться n первых слагаемых разложения. Значение n определяет пользователь.

Пока реализовал данную программу для sin(x). Возникает проблема в том, как составить формулу для разложения функции sin(x)+cos(x) в ряд Тейлора на С++. Переискал по этому поводу все источники в Интернете - результат нулевой. Буду очень благодарен.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Node {
private:
    float x;
    int n;

public:
    Node();
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Node&);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&, Node&);
};

Node::Node() {
    x = 0;
    n = 0;

}

istream& operator >> (istream& in, Node& tam) {
    cout << "Введите x: ";
    in >> tam.x;
    cout << "Введите n: ";
    in >> tam.n;
    return in;
}
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Node& tam) {
    float gh = 0.0;
    for (int st = 1; st <= tam.n; st++) {
        gh = exp((st*(log(tam.x)))) / st;
        gh = tam.x / st;
        out << "(" << gh << ")" << "+" << gh << "";
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    Node tam;
    cin >> tam;
    cout << tam;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Откровенно говоря, не вижу у вас формулы для синуса... И - вам в каком виде нужно выводить? Напишите руками пример для того же синуса для первых нескольких членов. То, что выводится у вас - простите, какой-то бред...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если вы в состоянии написать для синуса (и уверены, что сделали это верно), то просто воспользуйтесь тем, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так что ряда для синуса вполне должно хватить :) - ну, потребуется членов для сходимости чуть побольше, но не так уж и намного...

Если нет... Ну, тогда очень небольшие размышления говорят о том, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заметим также, что очередной член получается из предыдущего (не считая знака) умножением на `x` и делением на `k`, так что всякие логарифмы (к тому же не работающие для отрицательных значений) и экспоненты совершенно не нужны.

Надеюсь, этих подсказок достаточно, чтоб написать код?

Я бы набросал его за вас, но из вашего условия не понимаю, в каком именно виде нужен вывод. Ваш вывод типа

```
(1)+1(0.5)+0.5(0.333333)+0.333333(0.25)+0.25(0.2)+0.2(0.166667)+0.166667
```

считать образцом никак не могу...

P.S. Ряд Тейлора обладает еще одним параметром - точкой x<sub>0</sub>, относительно которой все это строится. Вы по умолчанию считаете ее равной 0, т.е. работаете с рядом Маклорена. Это просто так, терминологическое примечание.

P.P.S. К тому, кто поставил минус - просьба указать, какую ошибку вы у меня нашли, и написать свой, математически *более правильный* ответ :)

P.P.P.S. Для особо одаренных - реализация сказанного [в виде кода](https://ideone.com/wN9zoN).

Comment: За формулу - огромное спасибо! Уже все дописал и исправил ошибки...